# HTTP GET not working in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, get, http-get

Here is my controller, being served from localhost port 80:

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/moz').success(function (data) {
        $scope.moz = data;
    });
}
```

And the output from curl:

```
curl -i localhost/api/moz
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date: Tue, 21 May 2013 13:35:43 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4
Content-Type: application/json

[{"sID": 0, "sName": "Sa"},{"sID": 0, "sName": "Ab"},{"sID": 0, "sName": "Ds A"}]
```

Unfortunately the output from `{{moz}}` is `[]`.

Been working on this for many hours now, and have no clue how to get it to work. My scaffold is identical to step5 of the angularjs tutorial.

Comment: Seems to be something to do with the status code... :\

Comment: 302 Found is a redirect. You should find out why that isn't a 200.

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving an array, and need to iterate over it. Try this in your template:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="m in moz">{{m.sName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still getting no content (blank screen... 'Inspect element' shows: `<ul><!-- ngRepeat: m in phones --></ul>` there.

Comment: @user2283066 Why are you doing m in phones? Phones isn't bound to your scope, "moz" is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only status-code supported by the `success` promise function is 200.

So going against the standard I have made all my "successful" returns HEAD 200.

It is now working.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "going against the standard"?